# who to send data through angular router

Tags: angular

I have one component `sidebar` rendered like this :

`default-layout.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'fbo-default-layout',
  styleUrls: ['./default-layout.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <div class="root">

      <div class="wrapper-bar">
        <fbo-header></fbo-header>
        <fbo-sidebar (changeSidebarPosition)="onChangeSidebarPosition($event)">
        </fbo-sidebar>
      </div>

      <div class="app sidebar-is-{{sidebarPosition}}">
        <div class="app-container">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class LayoutComponent {
  // .......
}
```

The other component is rendered via the router :

`app-routing.module.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  /* MODEL */
  {
    path: 'models',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [{ path: '', component: ModelsTableComponent }],
  },

  // other route ........
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    useHash: true, /* hash routing see https://angular.io/guide/router#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles */
    enableTracing: !environment.noRouterLog && !environment.production, /* routing debug log only in dev */
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', /* give the possibility to have a refresh button */
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

In component charged by the router I have some http request.
In this request I calculate the time taken by each of them to resolve.

I want to send this data, when the request is finished, to my `sidebar`.

What is the way to do that?

Comment: A service would be the way to go since you are using router outlet: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: works very well w/ a service, @AT82 if you want to post an answer I will validate it